# How to get an activity result while in Android PIP mode?

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I noticed that while an Activity is in picture-in-picture (PIP) mode in Android it does not appear to receive results were requested via `startActivityForResult(...)`. Unless I am doing something wrong? I wrote a bare bones sample app that goes into PIP mode and then starts an activity for result which calls `setResult(...)` and `finish` so I don't think I could have messed this up.

I am assuming this bug is probably an unintended side-effect of the differences in Activity lifecycle for activities that are  running in PIP mode; they seem to be in the "started but paused" state most of the time and not resumed.

Maybe someone has a workaround to get the result some other way? Although I guess reflection isn't possible now that Android P is restricted non-SDK interfaces. It seems the best we can do is invent another mechanism to send results which uses broadcasts but that wouldn't work with existing Activities that are built-in such as getting results from `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: Nope, but I am curious if multi-resume will apply to PIP in which case the issue might go away on newer platforms, see https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/11/get-your-app-ready-for-foldable-phones.html

Answer (score 1):

Following this post https://proandroiddev.com/task-management-for-picture-in-picture-mode-on-android-o-882103271cad , we override the Activity method `finish()` to  check when the PIP mode was launched, if so, we navigate to the launcher activity before calling the super class method for the the activity result logic to work.

This is the code to navigate to the launcher activity

```
override fun finish() {
        if (pictureInPictureLaunched) navToLauncherTask()
        super.finish()
    }

fun navToLauncherTask() {
        val activityManager = baseContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
        // iterate app tasks available and navigate to launcher task (browse task)
        val appTasks = activityManager.appTasks
        for (task in appTasks) {
            val baseIntent = task.taskInfo.baseIntent
            val categories = baseIntent.categories
            if (categories != null && categories.contains(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)) {
                task.moveToFront()
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

<del>I guess that's because when the activity enters PIP mode, it will be put into a new task with the flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html?hl#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).
According to the official docs, this flag doesn't allow us to request a result from the caller activity.</del>

> This flag can not be used when the caller is requesting a result from the activity being launched.

<del>To solve this issue, maybe we can use other libraries like [eventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to send the activity finish() event and data.</del>

Comment: I actually meant that my activity A is running in PIP mode and I started yet another activity B for result. When I started activity B I didn't use the NEW_TASK flag.

Comment: ah, sorry for misunderstanding your question, please ignore this answer.